# YouTube Api only triggered at hard reload

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube-api

I seem to have an issue with my yotube iframe Api only being triggered at hard reload and not normal reloads?

How come is that, and is there any way to trigger this hard reload using javascript?

This is how I am currently using it..

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      const a = document.createElement('script');
      a.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
      const scriptref = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      scriptref.parentNode.insertBefore(a, scriptref);
    });

window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {

  $('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').each(function() {
    const id = $(this).attr('id');
    const src = $(this).attr('src');
    const videoId = youtubeParser(src);
    window.tdcplayers[id] = new youTubeApi.Player(id ,{
      enablejsapi: 1,
      videoId: videoId
    });
}
```

I am currently running two youtube API, and one of the breaks, unless I hard reloads, someway i can come around this`?

Comment: Please take a refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask good and clear questions.

Comment: you need to add code in question and also as much detail as possible...